# How to load "context.xml" from classpath in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, ldap, classpath

I am trying to load my spring context.xml file using Java from the classpath. My `context.xml` file is in `src/main/resources`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = null;
    try {
        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:context.xml");
        context.registerShutdownHook();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (context != null) {
            context.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Above code works fine when I am running in my eclipse. But as soon as I package it into a runnable jar by right  clicking the project and select export as a runnable jar and then run the jar from a ubuntu  machine as -

```
java -jar test.jar
```

Then I am getting below exception -

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at com.host.sd.corp.ldap.Application.main(Application.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
        ... 18 more
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't include the resources in `src/main/resources` in your jar. I don't believe the Maven plugin is involved in Eclipse's Jar Export utility.

Comment: How I exported the runnable jar was - Right  click on project which I am working on, export as a runnable jar, select  launch configuration, and click Package required libraries into generated Jar. Is this wrong?

Comment: @AKIWEB Does the Launch configuration you selected have the included resource in its classpath?

Comment: How do Ii verify that? Because as soon as I right click the  project and click `export` and then click `Runnable Jar File`, it just shows Launch Configuration in which I have selected my main class and destination for my jar file and then click `Package required libraries into generated Jar`. So I am not sure how do I verify that?

Comment: @AKIWEB In the menu bar, there's the Run menu which let's you look at launch configurations. Check the one that you selected while exporting.

Comment: Ok. In my launch configuration, I got the `Classspath` tab and I only have two entries there, `Bootstrap Entries` and User `Entries`. In the user entries, I have my project but I don't my resources over there? Am I looking at right place?

Comment: @AKIWEB I think so. You need to add the `/src/main/resources` to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55285/discussion-between-akiweb-and-sotirios-delimanolis).